# Follow AJAX 13 bytes - Twitter

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

When following an account on Twitter, a POST request is sent saying that we are following that person.

The thing is that the request does only take 13 bytes. I was kinda stoked when I found about this because it will reduce the latency (I am just sending a small amount of information) and the load on the server. It can give web developers loads of advantages.

But how can they even send an XMLHttpRequest and removing the cookies and all the extra information that is unneeded? From what I've heard is that there is no way of removing the extra information (security reasons).

Is there a way of doing the same as Twitter does here or is it simply just out of my leaugue?[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: What information is sent in the Request Headers? (sorry, I'm at work, so I can't check it out for myself)

Answer (score 2):

"13B" is the size of the response body, not the request.

Comment: How come mine does take 171 bytes? :O

Comment: Because there are 171 bytes in your response?

Comment: Is there possible to make this smaller?

Comment: Sure - put less data in your response.

Comment: But I only send 5 bytes max of information. I just send a GET request with a HTTP header containing a variable and some numbers.

Comment: I'm seeing those "13 bytes" aswell even with my connection turned off, so it's definitively not the response size, but it doesn't seem to be the request size either. Perhaps it really is just a random artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "13B" thing is just some transitory rendering artifact within Chrome's inspector. After the response actually comes back, it's a proper value (which denotes the size of the response, not the request), as others have noted.

Note that you will not see the same "13B" thing if you look at Firebug inside Firefox. Nor will you see it if you use a proxy sniffer tool like Charles.

Comment: It makes sense, but I thought it wasn't allowed